# Firing too many events when adding a listener to my sprites

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am trying to create a basic Cocos2d-js example with a bunch of balls that I can click to move. I'm creating the balls like this:

```
        var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
            event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
            swallowTouches: false,
            onTouchBegan: ballTouchBeganEventHandler
        });

        var BallTile = cc.Sprite.extend({
            ctor: function(image, position)
            {
                this._super();
                var ballSize = g_settings.ballSize;
                this.initWithFile(image, cc.rect(0, 0, ballSize, ballSize));
                this.setPosition(position);
                cc.eventManager.addListener(listener.clone(), this);
            }
        });

        var ball1 = new BallTile(ballImage1, ballPosition1);
        var ball2 = new BallTile(ballImage2, ballPosition2);
        var ball3 = new BallTile(ballImage3, ballPosition3);
```

The problem is that no matter which of the balls I click the event is fired three times (once for every ball) instead of just once for the ball that was clicked. 
I am using the same event listener for every ball but I would have imagined that it would only fire once for the ball that was actually clicked, not once of every ball having that has the event listener.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you set `swallowTouches` to `true`, and then make sure to return `true` from inside `ballTouchBeganEventHandler`?

Comment: @AndersKellerCarstensen: that was it. Please add it as an answer and I'll rightly award you with a green check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `swallowTouches` to `true`, and then make sure to return `true` from inside `ballTouchBeganEventHandler`.